# How to stop sound playing again when navigating to another form

Tags: c#, audio

I'm currently writing an app in c#, where this app will play background music once it started. And the button clicking sound and music shall stop when I press the mute button, or play again when unmuted.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class mainMenu : Form
{
    public bool sound = true; //variable of whether the sound is on or not
    System.Media.SoundPlayer bgm = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\HCI\New folder\bgm.wav");

    public bool soundval //for other form to access sound variable value
    {
        get
        {
            return sound;
        }

        set
        {
            sound = value;
        }
    }

    public mainMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        play();
    }

    public void play() //function to play music
    {
        bgm.PlayLooping();
    }

    public void stop//function to stop music
    {
        bgm.Stop();
    }
    private void soundButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //button that mute or unmute the sound (by changing sound value)
    {
        if (sound)
        {
            bgm.Stop();
            sound = false;
        }
        else
        {
            var p2 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
            p2.Open(new System.Uri(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\HCI\New folder\button.wav"));
            p2.Play();
            play();
            sound = true;
        }
    }
    private void easy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //proceed to other form
    {
        if (sound)
        {
            var p2 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
            p2.Open(new System.Uri(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\HCI\New folder\button.wav"));
            p2.Play();
        }

        Easy game2 = new Easy();
        game2.Tag = this;
        game2.Show(this);
        Hide();
    }
    }
}
```

Until here, the app works fine. But then if I muted the sound and proceed to other form, the music will play again, the button sound will also play if I press anything on any button on that particular form.

Partial code of my other form(easy_Click):

```
mainMenu mmenu = new mainMenu();
private void thirdchoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mmenu.soundval) //to get the value from first form, button sound should play only when value is true
        {
            var p2 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
            p2.Open(new System.Uri(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\HCI\New folder\button.wav"));
            p2.Play();
        }
        if (ansNum == choice3num) goodnews();
        else badnews();
    }
```

Not only music, but the button clicking sound is playing as well. It looks like the sound value set to true when proceed to second form, even though it was false in first form.
I been stuck on this issue for a long time, changing here and there, but nothing work.
Really appreciate if someone could help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Was no, now done reading. But at here, Im able to stop the sound, but it play AGAIN (automatically), once the app navigate to another form.

Comment: I have removed the duplicate

Comment: You write `new mainMenu` it means it load default values from starting. But if you want the changed values to consider than don't use `new mainMenu` as it will load new class and in mainMenu you set `soundval=true.`

Comment: I see, that explained why, I will try to work around with that. Thanks @Abhiverma